# Trouble trying to run an application in Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make a simple app, a quizz with five questions with true or false answers, but when I click on the "Run" option nothing appears on the screen of my smartphone. However, Android Studio indicates me that the app is running. How can I fix this?

### Code of the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/erstructuraLista"
        android:layout_width="336dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/estructuraPreguntas">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/anterior"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="anterior"
            android:text="Anterior"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:icon="?attr/actionModeCloseDrawable" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/siguiente"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="siguente"
            android:text="Siguiente"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:icon="?attr/actionModeCloseDrawable" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pregunta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Lista de Preguntas"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/estructuraPreguntas"
        android:layout_width="336dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pregunta">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/verdadero"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Verdadero"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/falso"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Falso"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/respuesta"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Respuesta"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/erstructuraLista"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/estructuraPreguntas"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.328" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Code of the Kotlin file "Pregunta"

```
class Pregunta {
    var pregunta : String = ""
    var resultado : Boolean = true

    constructor(pregunta : String, resultado : Boolean) {
        this.pregunta = pregunta
        this.resultado = resultado
    }

    fun verPregunta() : String = pregunta
    fun verResultado() : Boolean = resultado

    fun darPregunta(p : String) { pregunta = p }
    fun darResultado(r : Boolean) { resultado = r }
}
```

### Code of the Kotlin file Buzz

class Buzz {
var listaPreguntas = ArrayList()

```
constructor() {
    listaPreguntas.add(Pregunta("¿Es el cielo  azul?", true) )
    listaPreguntas.add(Pregunta("¿Batman es Bruce Wayne?", true) )
    listaPreguntas.add(Pregunta("¿La Tierra es plana?", false) )
    listaPreguntas.add(Pregunta("¿La fuerza es el producto de la masa de un cuerpo multiplicado por su aceleraci\u00F3n?", true) )
    listaPreguntas.add(Pregunta("¿Es la máquina de Turin el ordenador más antiguo del mundo?", true) )
}

fun darPregunta(puesto : Int) : String = listaPreguntas.get(puesto).verPregunta()
fun darRespuesta(puesto : Int) : String {
    if(listaPreguntas.get(puesto).verResultado() == true) {
        return "Verdadero"
    } else {
        return "Falso"
    }
}
```

}

### Code of the Kotlin file Main

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        this.textopregunta.setText(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(0).verPregunta() )
    }

    fun siguente(view : View) {
        if(this.textopregunta.text.toString().equals(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(0).verPregunta() ) ) {
            this.textopregunta.setText(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(1).verPregunta() )
        } else if(this.textopregunta.text.toString().equals(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(1).verPregunta() ) ) {
            this.textopregunta.setText(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(2).verPregunta() )
        } else if(this.textopregunta.text.toString().equals(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(2).verPregunta() ) ) {
            this.textopregunta.setText(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(3).verPregunta() )
        } else if(this.textopregunta.text.toString().equals(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(3).verPregunta() ) ) {
            this.textopregunta.setText(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(4).verPregunta() )
        } else if(this.textopregunta.text.toString().equals(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(4).verPregunta() ) ) {
            this.textopregunta.setText(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(0).verPregunta() )
        }
    }

    fun anterior(view : View) {
        if(this.textopregunta.text.toString().equals(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(0).verPregunta() ) ) {
            this.textopregunta.setText(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(4).verPregunta() )
        } else if(this.textopregunta.text.toString().equals(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(1).verPregunta() ) ) {
            this.textopregunta.setText(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(0).verPregunta() )
        } else if(this.textopregunta.text.toString().equals(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(2).verPregunta() ) ) {
            this.textopregunta.setText(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(1).verPregunta() )
        } else if(this.textopregunta.text.toString().equals(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(3).verPregunta() ) ) {
            this.textopregunta.setText(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(2).verPregunta() )
        } else if(this.textopregunta.text.toString().equals(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(4).verPregunta() ) ) {
            this.textopregunta.setText(buzz.listaPreguntas.get(3).verPregunta() )
        }
    }

    var buzz : Buzz = Buzz()
    var textopregunta : TextView = this.findViewById(R.id.pregunta)
    var textorepuesta : TextView = this.findViewById(R.id.respuesta)
    var pulsarverdadero : Button = this.findViewById(R.id.verdadero)
    var pulsarfalso : Button = this.findViewById(R.id.falso)
    var pulsaranterior : Button = this.findViewById(R.id.anterior)
    var pulsarsiguiente : Button = this.findViewById(R.id.siguiente)
}
```